# Is there any method to get system-defined directory's localized display name on macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to get system-defined directories' (eg Desktop, Documents, Downloads) localized display names same as shown in Finder's Favorites.

I tried using `NSFileManager`'s `displayNameAtPath`: but it only worked for custom Directory.localized directory containing `*.` strings files and not worked for system-defined directories.

Below is my code I checked this with.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if (argc < 2) {
        // Use ~/Application directory if no command line arguments are provided
        NSString *localizedApplicationDirectoryName = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationDirectory, NSLocalDomainMask, YES).lastObject];
        NSLog(@"%@", localizedApplicationDirectoryName);
        [pool drain];
        return 1;
    }

    // Use command line arguments
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *directory = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
    NSString *displayName = [fileManager displayNameAtPath:directory];    
    NSLog(@"%@", displayName);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Are there another methods to get this translations?

Answer (score 1):

Get the localized name from the URL for example the desktop folder

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory()] URLByAppendingPathComponent: @"Desktop"];
NSString *localizedName;
NSError *error;
[url getResourceValue:&localizedName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", localizedName);
}
```

Comment: It works the same way as my code. I only see translated directory names for custom Directory.localized directories whereas system-defined directories stay nonlocalized.